# Show only past years with bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have Bootstrap 3 Datepicker input for selection of a birth day. I found a great feature `viewMode: 'years'`, when selection dialog starts from years, but Datapicker shows years from -5 to +5 from current, obviously nobody still was born in the future, so I restricted dates by `maxDate: moment()`, but future years are still shown though are disabled, moreover - this added initial value of current day to the input, and `defaultDate: false` doesn't fix this!

So, at least I could set `maxDate` as today-5 years to avoid future years, but it would set current value which is undesired.

**ADDED**: future years still shown, still looking for method to avoid them.

How could I restrict dates and avoid initial value in the same time?

https://codepen.io/zzmaster/pen/KQmdrJ

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
        viewMode: 'years',
        maxDate: moment(),
        defaultDate: false
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you want to be the default value?

Comment: Try using `useCurrent: false` instead of `defaultDate: false`. Docs: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent

Comment: NiK648, great, it works, thanks! Sorry, I cannot set comment as solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
        viewMode: 'years',
        maxDate: moment(),
        useCurrent: false
    });
});
```

Credit:  NiK648

Comment: useCurrent, not currentDate. And, yes Credit: NiK648

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not solution to prevent picker from showing future years, the workaround is to hide them:

```
#datetimepicker  .disabled {
      display: none;
    }
```